# Why is my "req" undefined? "TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to implement authentication middleware to my routes in an Express Router.

When the router goes to the middleware and tries to read the `req.headers["authorization"]`, I get the error:

```
const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
                         ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'headers' of undefined
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here, I've gone through the [Express router middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html#middleware.router) but couldn't find my answers there.

I have also tried not calling `router.use(authenticateToken());` like this `router.use(authenticateToken);` and get this error: `TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object`

Below is the middleware function and the route that I tried to use it on. [Here](https://github.com/gary-kaufman/News-API) is the project on GitHub in its current state.

```
// Authenticate Token!
authenticateToken = function (req, res, next) {
  const authHeader = req.headers["authorization"];
  console.log(authHeader);
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  if (token == null) {
    return res.sendStatus(401);
  } else {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, username) => {
      if (err) {
        return res.sendStatus(403);
      } else {
        req.username = username;
        next();
      }
    });
  }
};
router.use(authenticateToken());

router.get("/", authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find();
    res.status(200).json(users);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Even console log req?

Comment: Yes. With a console.log(req) I get back undefined.

Comment: Change this `router.use(authenticateToken());` to this `router.use(authenticateToken);`

Comment: I tried that and got this error:
``` TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object ```

Answer (score 3):

You are incorrectly registering your middleware.

You have

```
router.get("/", authenticateToken(), async ...
```

while it should be

```
router.get("/", authenticateToken, async ...
```

The first incorrect version of yours tries to immediately call the method. Instead, the method reference should be passed to router so that it's the pipeline that calls you.

Comment: I tried that and got a the error: "TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object" to which I added the line "router.use(authenticateToken());" and it brings back the original error.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should define your middleware like this:

```
router.get("/", authenticateToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const users = await User.find();
    res.status(200).json(users);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried that and got a the error: "TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a Object" to which I added the line "router.use(authenticateToken());" and it brings back the original error.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! And sadly, it was unrelated to the code and question I had above.

I was missing the line
`module.exports = router;`
at the bottom of the file!

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Still, it's highly unlikely your middleware registration would work with () after function name. This would call the function rather than pass it as an argument.